# Footer's width is not 100% when browser window is resized

Tags: html, css

I have two div's. One that's the body of my page and other that's the footer of my page. The footer div should have 100% of width, even when I resize browser window.

My webpage is in this way:

[image]

When I resize browser window the scroll appears:

[image]

If I scroll the page horizontally, my footer isn't 100% of width anymore:

[image]

What should I do to keep my footer div always 100% of width?

```
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>

#header {
    height: 500px;
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: grey;
}

#footer {
    background: #6B191C;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just find a solution here: http://www.impressivewebs.com/fluid-header-footer-problem/

Setting a min-width to the footer with the same width of the main div (1100px).

I changed the css of my footer to this:

```
#footer {
    background: #6B191C;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    min-width: 1100px;
}
```

And added some properties to the body:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

This link shows a webpage with this problem and another one with the solution applied: http://www.impressivewebs.com/demo-files/fluid-header-footer/

Answer (score 1):

Use `vw` instead of `%`. 1vh equals to 1% of browsers viewport.

```
#footer {
    background: #6B191C;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100vw;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```

There are more relative lengths than just `vw`. There is:

- `vh` - Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport
- `vw` - Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport
- `vmin` - Relative to 1% of viewport's smaller dimension
- `vmax` - Relative to 1% of viewport's larger dimension

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

Comment: @PedroEstevao It's not working because you have got some margins and paddings in your `body`. You have to reset it with `body{margin: 0;padding: 0}`

Comment: I added body{margin: 0;padding: 0;} exactly as you said in my css file and still didn't work.

Comment: That's because your website is way too high and is adding scrollbar, sadly vw ignores scrollbar, so check my other answer that should fit you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width` from your footer and add `right: 0;` instead. It will spread your footer from the left side to the right side. So your CSS will be this:

```
#footer {
    background: #6B191C;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```

Here is working example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwRJqv.

Comment: Still didn't work. I checked your example and it didn't work too.

Comment: How so my example is not working? I just tried to open it with Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Internet Explorer. It works everywhere. Send me a picture of it not working in your browser.

Comment: Also, what's your screen resolution? Because your header div is 1100 pixels wide, That's why it's creating scrollbar.

Comment: My screen resolution is 1920x1080. Here's the picture of your example not working on my screen: http://s8.postimg.org/u4qa3f6th/654.jpg

Comment: I have no idea why that doesnt work for you, it works for everyone else but you. What browser do you use?

Comment: I tested on Chrome and IE10.

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea why that doesnt work for you and works for other. :/

Comment: I find a solution and posted an answer here. But thanks very much for the help.

Comment: @Kyrbi Your pen doesn't work for me either - if I shrink my window, the footer is the width of the window rather than the content, so if I scroll horizontally I see white background.

Answer (score 0):

Most reasonable cause would be that your #footer id contains the **properties**

```
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
```

which is effecting the layout of `width: 100%;` inside your *#footer* so for the quickest fix would be removing those properties to bring back the normal flow of the element.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work just removing these properties.